# how to prevent applications to be installed in Android phone

Tags: android

I am developing a customer care android application. The client want that only the customer care application should be installed in the Android phone and we should prevent installation of other application. Is there any hack we can do to do that?

Comment: Short of creating your own ROM, which does not allow applications to be installed, not really. You could root the device, and lock it down by disabling the device's permissions to install apps, but you would need to find or develop another application to do this as well.

Comment: well root to device is differ from device to device. So we can't write app for each device. is there any common solution for it?

Comment: Rooting a device is different, root operations on a device are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any hack we can do to do that?

Fortunately, not from a standard SDK app -- the technical term for this would be "malware".

As the comments to your question indicate, you are welcome to root the device, remove the Google Play Store client (if it exists), and disable the ability to install from non-Play sources by adjusting the secure settings. However, I suspect that this will prevent you from updating your own app without rooting.